# WCF Restful Service with Service certificate

Tags: wcf, security, rest, service, certificate

I have develop a securized WCF Service with wsHttpBinding using ssl and a ***SERVICE certificate*** (not a client certificate, but a service one!). Only clients storing the self signed certificate in their certificate store will be allowed to consume the service.

I used a configuration similar as :

```
<security mode="Transport">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
   <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
</security>

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CertificateServiceBehavior">
            <serviceCredentials>
...
                <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="server" />
            </serviceCredentials>
...
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

---

I am quite new to WCF Securisation. I've search a lot a bout securisation but i need you to help me out with my questions.

Today I was asked to securize a WCF Restful service.
Looking over internet I have found that we could :

- use ssl
- authenticate client with Credential (using  => Certificate =
  Client Certificate)

My questions are:

a) From my first example at the beginning, I have assumed that when we setup a service certificate, this isto securize a wcf service at the **message** level
(in comparaison with transport, as ssl is taking care of transport). 
Please correct me if i am wrong ?

b) For WCF Restful Service, the binding we use is WebHttpBinding.
According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb412176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
there is no   element under :

```
 <security mode="None/Transport/TransportCredentialOnly">
    // here there is only <transport> available with clientCredential="certificate" available.
 </security>
```

So, could we setup a **service certificate** for a restful Service?

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I had a bit of difficulty understanding the details of your question, but discerned (hopefully correctly) that you are looking for recommendations to secure your WCF service with certificates.  When facing a similar consideration, our team found that the following MSDN article provided a comprehensive and easy to understand walk-through of Message Security with Mutual Certificates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733102(v=vs.110).aspx

The article clearly indicates the necessary requirements and provides code and configuration examples.

Regards,

Comment: I've read a lot and i get  so confuse.
 
What i mean is, as you can see in your link : to  set up a server certificate, we use `<security mode="message" />`.

To make it short : i am not sure we could do the same with a WCF rest service as we can only set `<security mode="Transport"/"None"/"Basic"/"TransportWithCredential" />` (because of the WebHttpBinding documentation).
I wanted a confirmation.

So Instead i guess I could do with a client certificate only (still in the case of a Rest service)

Comment: I think I understand ... you want to use Transport Security with Certificate Authentication.  Check the following links which should provide the details necessary to clarify:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650785.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348595/Use-Mutual-SSL-Authentication-in-WCF

Comment: This might be just what you need:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bradleycotier/archive/2011/12/14/mutual-authentication-with-a-iis-hosted-wcf-data-service-installed-in-a-workgroup-environment.aspx

Comment: Thank you, the 2nd link is really useful, it exposes mutual authentification, i understand better : 

we can see that the client can authenticate with a certificate and how to configure on the Server side to authorize the clients. 

We can also see that the client can identify the server having its a certificate : this is not the "service certificate" (message) i was asking about, but i guess in case of security transport (and Rest Service), the server can only authenticad with the ssl certificate (transport Security).